# I have a ps4 and I just got it. I have entered a redeem code wrong to many times. How long till I can redeem my codes again

Tags: ps4

please help me I need to know asap. I have looked up how long it takes but I cant seem to find out. I lost my code and I tried to enter it because I thaught i could remember it and I entered it to many times.

Answer (score 0):

The lockout for PS3 lasted 24 hours, and I found nothing to suggest that this is different for the PS4.